# Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha\,f(yz)+\beta\,f(zx)+\gamma\,f(xy)\geq f(x+y+z)$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

> Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be three real numbers.  Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$\alpha\,f(yz)+\beta\,f(zx)+\gamma\,f(xy)\geq f(x+y+z)$$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Remarks.**

- If $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$, then any function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$ is a solution.
- If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$, then any constant function $f$ satisfies the functional inequality.
- If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma>1$, then any nonnegative constant function $f$ satisfies the functional inequality.
- If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma<1$, then any nonpositive constant function $f$ satisfies the functional inequality.

**Special Case.**  (The idea was borrowed from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616019/functional-equation-f-bbb-r-to-bbb-r/2616050#2616050), which is a particular case with $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\dfrac13$.)

Suppose that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$. Without loss of generality, $\alpha\leq \beta\leq \gamma$. Plugging in $y:=0$ and $z:=0$, we get $$f(x)\leq f(0)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Note that $\gamma>0$.  Plugging in $y:=-x$ and $z:=0$, we have $$f(0)\geq f(-x^2)\geq f(0)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This means $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\leq 0$.  Now, by letting $y:=x$ and $z:=-2x$, we have
$$f(0)\geq f(+x^2)\geq f(0)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This means $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\geq 0$.  Therefore, $f(x)=f(0)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Hence, if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$, then the only solutions $f$ are constant functions.

What are solutions for other parameters $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$?  Can we hope to find all solutions $f$ for an arbitrary triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$?  If this is too difficult, can we at least hope for a characterization of all solutions $f$ if $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$?

**Postscript.**  If we have an equality instead, that is, $$\alpha\,f(yz)+\beta\,f(zx)+\gamma\,f(xy)=f(x+y+z)$$
for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$, then by plugging $y,z:=0$, we get $f(x)=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\,f(0)$.  In particular, when $x:=0$, we have
$$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma-1)\,f(0)=0\,.$$
Thus, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$ or $f(0)=0$.

If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$, then using the same argument as the proof of the "Special Case" above, we can see that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  That is, $f$ is a constant function.

If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma\neq 1$, then $f(0)=0$.  Using the same argument as the proof of the "Special Case" above, we can see that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  That is, $f$ is the zero function.

Comment: I did $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$  and $f(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2} \; . \; \;$ Seems promising

Comment: hmmm it kind of appears that the highest degree term in the resulting numerator is $-x^4 y^4 z^4$ while denominator has degree 14 as $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)x^4 y^4 z^4,$ if that holds up the difference can be made negative at large $x=y=z.$ That should be easy enough to check...

Comment: yeah, with $x=y=z=t$   the difference has positive denominator but numerator $2 + 27 t^2 - t^4$